# how to write jest test cases for an function inside functional Component

Tags: react-native, jestjs

i need to write test case for foo function which is called from child component inside child component childFun function

**Parent.js**

```
const Parent = ()=>{

const foo =()=>{
console.log("hello world")
}

return <Child foo={foo}/>
}
```

**Child.js**

```
const Child =({foo})=>{

const childFun=(e)=>{
    foo()
}
return (
<View onLayout={childFun}>
<Text>child views</Text>
</View>
)
}
```

Comment: Could you give some more details on what it is you’re trying to do or the problem you’re having? What test are you trying to do?

Comment: Hi David,
i need to write test case to invoke parent component function i.e foo() from child component onlayout event using jest

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense. So what aspect are you caught on? Mocking the parent or function while testing the child? Triggering the onlayout event? Or something else?

Comment: mocking the parent function "foo()"

Comment: In that case, in your test you should be able to just pass in a mocked function to the foo prop of Child. Perhaps you could add your code from attempting to write the test, share any specific framework or tools you’re using, and any other pertinent details to help us see where exactly you’re stuck?

Comment: its an banking based application so its confidential i not able to share further details
framework:
React native
Jest
react-test-renderer